# Difficulty proving that diagonal matrix of A's distinct eigenvalues is similair to A.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to understand why a matrix of distinct eigenvalues to $A$ is similair to $A$, that is, has the same element as any other diagonal matrix similair to $A$ (though possibly in different positions).

Eigenvalues are easily defined, as values $\lambda_i$ satisfying $|A - \lambda_i*I|=0$, but defining the elements of some diagonal matrix similair to $A$, i am finding quite difficult.

A diagonal matrix similair to $A$, should be a matrix $D$, such that a $P$ in $P^-1 *D*P=A$ exists.

The equation can be rewritten:
$ \frac{1}{|P|} Adjucate(P)*   \begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1*p_{1,1} & \dots & p_{1,n}\\\vdots & \ddots &\vdots\\ p_{n,1} & \dots & \lambda_n*p_{n,n}  \end{bmatrix}=A$
$\rightarrow A_{i,j}= \frac{1}{|P|} *\sum_{k=1}^n (<P_{k,i}>*P_{k,j} *\lambda_i)$

(where $<P_{k,i}>$ is the $k,i$ cofactor of $P$). But from here i cannot seem to get further in the proof. Another thing im pondering about is whether this at all needs a proof, or that there's something obivous here i am not realizing.

Comment: A matrix with distinct eigenvalues over a field $F$ is [diagonalizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix).

Comment: If you’re going to work with this definition of eigenvalue, consider $\det(D-\lambda I)$ and its implications for the elements of $D$.